# Why is my 4 year old pooping inside when Im gone?

Tags: toilet-training, german-shepherd

My 4 year old german shepherd is pooping and peeing inside, but only when I’m gone! Why??

He has no health issues and doesn’t appear to have separation anxiety (doesn’t chew things up, doesn’t bark, doesn’t act out). He NEVER goes potty inside when i’m home. it’s only ever when i’m absent. he always goes out before i leave and they eat on a schedule-therefore he doesn’t eat before i leave.

We moved into a new home a year ago and he’s intermittently had this issue but now it seems to be the normal. I don’t punish him when i come home because i know he won’t associate the two. But i am tired of coming home to clean it. i’m going to start trying to lock him up in my bedroom because it’s only ever the same spot in the living room.

Does anyone else have any kind of advice or experiences with this?? i feel like i’ve failed with him and doing things wrong. please help:(

Comment: How long is the dog alone? Is there a time span short enough it does not poo and pee? One method would be to take this time span and enlarge it step by step.

Comment: Sometimes Im gone for my full 8 hour shift and he will not go potty inside. Sometimes Im gone for 2 hours and he will go potty inside. Hes super confusing lol. Sometimes he goes full potty inside, sometimes he just poops. Sometimes when I get home you can tell its fresh and other times you can tell it happened earlier in the day. 

I will try your method for sure though. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I know of people who have some kind of cat toilet for their dog, but I have no experience with this...